# Generic could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an `openModal` context function that takes a modal component, adds some custom close/etc logic, and renders them. The function call takes the component and props, not JSX because I needed to extract the return value for promise typing but that's unrelated to this issue - just explains why this is more complex than usual.

The modal components all extend `Closeable` but this `openModal` function supplies its own `onClose` to the modal component. So I wanted to omit `onClose` from the `props` argument this function accepts.

That works fine, however when I go to apply both `onClose` and the `props` argument to my Modal component, I get the following error:

```
Type { key: string; onClose: (result: R) => void } is not assignable to type 'I'
  I could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated
```

I'm obviously missing something. I thought `I extends Closeable` was enough to limit its time.

```
// Our modal components all extend Closeable
export interface Closeable<T = undefined> {
  onClose: (result: T) => void
}

const openModal= <
  I extends Closeable<any>,
  P = Omit<I, 'onClose'>,
  R = I extends Closeable<infer T> ? T : undefined
>(
  Modal: ComponentType<I>,
  ...props: keyof P extends never ? [] : [P]
): Promise<R> =>
  new Promise<R>(resolve => {
    const id = uuidv4()
    const onClose = (result: R): void => {}

    const element = <Modal key={id} onClose={onClose} {...(props.length > 0 ? props[0] : {})} />
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i can think of 2 solutions:
1.the easiest is in the props in the openModal function you can separate the onclose
Like this:

```js
 const openModal=(Modal,{onclose, ...props})=> {}
```

Or you can do the other solution which is create copy of the props where you send them into the function and delete there the on close.
I think the second one will be a better approach for you.

Comment: The type has already omitted the onClose method so it's not going to be passed in to begin with. `props` is a rest operator so it'll be an array, so your example isn't applicable to an array.